# How to parse remote html in ubuntu touch app

Tags: ubuntu-touch, remote, html, javascript

I am trying to find out if I can port a python based programm to ubuntu touch.

My program parses remote html pages for  items and then saves or streams the given link locally.

How do I parse a remote html page in an ubuntu touch app? Can it be done in javascript or does the same origin policy forbid it?

I would consider writing a scope as well so pointers in that direction would also be appreciated. I take it a c++ parser library is needed here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok in retrospect this was an exceedingly easy thing to solve.

In Ubuntu Touch QML/HTML5 Apps you can just do a standard XMLHTTP Request and then parse the returned html.

Here is an easy example:

```
function get_html($url){
    //This function gets the HTML Page at $url and saves the 
    //HTML Data in $html. 
    //This function is asynchronous! Actions like "return $html" will probably
    //not work as intended!

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
    var $html;
    xhr.open("GET", $url);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            $html = xhr.responseText
        }
    }
    xhr.send();
}
```